# AWS Cognito - Resetting User Password Documentation Seems to Contradict Itself

Tags: boto3, amazon-cognito

#### The Problem

I have worked with both AdminResetPassword and ForgotPassword and I found a contradiction in the API documentation that is confusing and seems to indicate there is no current solution for full admin initialized reset password flow.

The [AdminResetPassword documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminResetUserPassword.html) says:

> When a developer calls this API, **the current password is invalidated**, so it must be changed. If a user tries to sign in after the API is called, the app will get a PasswordResetRequiredException exception back and should direct the user down the flow to reset the password, **which is the same as the forgot password flow**.

However the [ForgotPassword documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ForgotPassword.html) states that ConfirmForgotPassword is part of the forgot password flow, and the [ConfirmForgotPassword documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ConfirmForgotPassword.html) requires the old password to be passed as part of the request. The password field is described as:

> The password sent by a user's request to retrieve a forgotten password.

So, the documentation claims AdminResetPassword and ForgotPassword use the same flow to reset the password, however, in reality, ForgotPassword allows the password to be recovered and AdminResetPassword invalidates the current password. It does not seem possible that the flows after this point could be the same.

#### The Questions

Is this an error in the documentation or am I misunderstanding how resetting passwords in aws cognito works?

If the two flows mentioned are different, what is the full flow for resetting passwords after they have been invalidated using AdminResetPassword?

Comment: Adding an auth challenge response to login attempts after the password has been invalidated, specifically using AdminResetPassword, seems like a logical addition. Then allow an AdminRespondToAuthChallenge to accept the verification code sent to the user, along with a new password. This would be very similar to the current flow of initial user login, using the temporary password the user received after an AdminCreateUser request. Instead of passing the new password and the temporary password in the AdminRespondToAuthChallenge, allow the verification code and the new password in the request.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alright, I don't like doing this, but I found my answer.

The documentation does have a few misleading points, as outlined below, but it is not necessarily explicitly incorrect.

1.) After calling both ForgotPassword and AdminResetPassword, the user's password is invalidated. In the case of AdminResetPassword, the user gets a "verification code" via email/sms, which is actually the "confirmation code" field with the ConfirmForgotPassword API method. This is misleading.

2.) In the ConfirmForgotPassword API call, the documentation describes the "password" field as:

> The password sent by a user's request to retrieve a forgotten password

however, this field is actually the new password to be set by the user.

3.) The documentation fails to note that the "secret hash" field is not required for clients that do not have a secret set.

So, ConfirmForgotPassword does work as the follow-up call for either AdminResetPassword or ForgotPassword, keeping the above points in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The latest doc says:

> SecretHash A keyed-hash message authentication code (HMAC) calculated
> using the secret key of a user pool client and username plus the
> client ID in the message.
>
> Type: String
>
> Length Constraints: Minimum length of 1. Maximum length of 128.
>
> Pattern: [\w+=/]+
>
> **Required: No**

so it is clear that secret hash is not required

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).